# Uploading and displaying images using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, upload

Are there tutorials that show you how to build an Rails application where you can upload and display images?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to checkout various [RailsCasts](http://www.railscasts.com):

- [#134 Paperclip](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip)
- [#253 CarrierWave File Uploads](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads)